# how to disable spring form checkbox?

Tags: spring, jsp

In my jsp, for certain conditions I want the checkbox to be present but do not want to allow the user to check it or uncheck it.

I am not sure how I can achieve this. I tried the following

```
<form:checkbox path="..." disabled = "disabled"> 
<form:checkbox path="..." disabled = "true"> 
<form:checkbox path="..." readonly = "readonly">
```

Nothing seem to work.

Can someone throw some light on this?

Thanks..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`disabled` attribute in `<spring:checkbox>` should be either set to `true` or `false` and  checkbox don't have `readonly` attribute. So

```
<form:checkbox path="corespondingPath" disabled = "true">
```

should work.

Few link
[Spring doc link.](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.checkbox)
[Readonly and Disabled property in Spring form input](http://www.developandconquer.com/2012/07/readonly-and-disabled-property-in.html)

You can use JSTL to add it depending on some condition

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${condition}">
          // Add checkbox with disabled="true"
          <form:checkbox path="desiredPAth" disabled="true" />
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
          // Do something else
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: A shorter way to do this could be **<form:checkbox path="desiredPAth" disabled="${requestScope.trueOrFalse}" />**

Comment: @OJVM Yes much cleaner.